# Visual Studio 2005 Quick find missing Search in solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

If I open a solution then press CTRL + F and select Quick Find, the Look in drop-down doesn't have "Entire solution" as an option (Find in files still has it).

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a response on Experts exchange(a community where experts in .Net answer), that option is missing in VS2005 pre-SP1. Install SP1 and it should be there.